# How do I set the PYTHON_PATH variable for my Google App Engine app?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I know you can set this in the Preferences of the SDK, but I worry that it won't be correct when the app is deployed.  What is the PYTHON_PATH value out on Google's Cloud?  Can I set this?

Going backwards a step, I just want to be able to do:

```
from something import something_else
```

My app can't resolve this reference, which is what led me to trying to get the PYTHON_PATH.

Comment: What error are you getting? Is `something_else` a module inside the `something` package, or a symbol inside the `something` module?

Comment: @Brandon:  I wish I could answer that correctly, but this is my first Python project.  I have a file called "something.py" in which I have a class defined called "something_else".  I'm trying to make that class available to my handler.

Comment: Where is 'something.py'? The simplest solution to making this work is to put it in the root directory of your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once your code is deployed, it will have access to all of the supported libraries without you taking any action. In order to add your application-specific directories to the path, you will need to do it programatically inside your handler. I use a pattern like this:

```
paths = [
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'mylib'),
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'app', 'tags'),
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'app', 'controllers'),
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'app', 'common'),
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'app', 'models'),
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'app')
]
for path in paths:
    if os.path.exists(path):
        # Don't add paths that don't exist.
        sys.path.append(path)
```

If you find that you are having a problem importing a module that is not part of your application, it may be that the module is not supported on AppEngine. See [the docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#Pure_Python) for more information.

EDIT:
Everyone structures their AppEngine applications a little differrently, but generally, you'll need to have this code at the main entry point for each .py file that is listed as a handler in your app.yaml. Generally, a handler file will have something that looks like this:

```
def main():
    # Do all of my initialization and run my
    # WSGIApplication

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

You can out the path-setting code inside the main() function.

Comment: Where do you put this code, normally?  Do you put it in every handler, or do you make a base handler and inherit your handlers from that?

Comment: @Deane: answered your question in the post.